# Proper way to return stl container

Tags: c++, stl

A lot of times, we need to return a container constructed inside a function. Say I have a function to get all primes in some range.

```
std::vector<int> getPrimes() {
    std::vector<int> primes;
    ...
    reutrn primes;
}
```

This seems need to copy all primes to the returned object. Then pointers are needed.

```
// =================Wrong code=================
// std::vector<int> *getPrimes() {
//     std::vector<int> primesptr;
//     ...
//     reutrn &primesptr;
// }
```

But apparently local variables cannot be returned. So the `new` operator can be used.

```
std::vector<int> *getPrimes() {
    std::vector<int> *primesptr = new std::vector<int>();
    ...
    reutrn primesptr;
}
```

Finally, this meets the need. But it's ugly and complicated (because of the usage of pointers). So what's the recommended way to return STL containers constructed inside a function? Moreover, if I return the STL container by value, will it be optimized so that only a constant amount of values or pointers are copied (instead of copying every element in the container)?

Comment: This seems need to copy all primes to the returned object. No, it's not so. Look for the keywords copy elision.

Comment: @S.M.: Or more specifically in this case, NRVO.

Comment: Or even just move constructors.

Comment: *Finally, this meets the need* -- It meets no need, except a good way to introduce memory leaks.  Also, it more than likely runs *slower* than simply returning the vector by value.  In this day and age of optimizing compiler, just return the `vector` by value.  There is no need to write tortured logic using pointers and dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: Re: "But apparently local variables cannot be returned" -- there's nothing wrong with returning local variables. The caution you might be thinking of is that you can't return **a reference** to a local variable; that is, `std::vector<int>& get_primes() { std::vector<int> primes; ... return primes; }` won't work.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah. I meant what you said but phrased it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a modern compiler, just use your original code; [NRVO (Named Return Value Optimization), a form of copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization), is performed by most modern compilers in the simple case you're demonstrating.

If for some reason you can't rely on this, and profiling shows this is a big problem on this crappy compiler you're using, you can, if you insist, explicitly do:

```
std::vector<int> getPrimes() {
    std::vector<int> primes;
    ...
    return std::move(primes);
}
```

This will prevent NRVO (so you'll definitely end up move-constructing the return value while destructing the emptied local variable), but move-construction of a `vector` is a fixed cost unrelated to the `vector`'s size (a handful of pointer and `size_t` assignments, the main backing array's storage is untouched).